# Por que quando troco de cena o DontDestroyOnLoad não funciona?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenho um `gameObject` com o script com todas as informações sobre o nível, xp e etc para o jogo. Ele é carregado na cena `Loader`, quando troco pra próxima cena, não quero perder esse `gameObject`.

Quando uso o `DontDestroyOnLoad`, ao invés dele manter o `gameObject` e carregar ele nas outras cenas, o nome da cena `Loader` se altera pro no nome do `gameObject`. E não aparece o `gameObject` nas outras cenas.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerStatsController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static PlayerStatsController instance;

    public int xpMultly = 1;
    public float xpFirstLevel = 100;
    public float difficultFactor = 1.5f;

    private float xpNextLevel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GamePlay");

    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é bem provavel que seja por causa do delay que a Unity usa entre o nativo e o managed, chama 'DontDestroyOnLoad' no Awake e o resto no 'start'.

Comment: Tente utilizar o DontDestoyOnLoad na função Awake, mas mesmo assim, onde tem anexado esse script?